# Can you sync a Document Set, instead of the entire Document Library?

Tags: 2013, document-library, document-set, sync

If you have a Document Set in a Document Library, is it possible to sync only the Document Set?

I created a Document Set, and altered the Welcome Page so that the Web Part was a Document Library, which enables syncing on that page.

However, when choosing to sync, it syncs the Document Library to which the Document Set belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, from a brief search it looks like the SkyDrive Pro sync service can only sync entire libraries, not parts of them.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2e4aa520-8c64-4cdc-b80b-4cf91413c81e/how-to-sync-only-subfolders-in-a-library-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

http://blog.technovert.com/2013/11/skydrive-pro-demystified/#more-143

Excerpt: With SkyDrive Pro Sync Client, there is no possibility to Sync a partial subset of a document library. By design the entire doc library gets synced and we get local copies of all the files and folders under it.